# How to select data from a table by referring to another table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables. `part` and `activity`. In part there are 4 columns. `pid` (part id), `aid` (activity id), `uname` (username) and `active`. In the activity tables there are a lot of rows like `aid, aname,adescription` etc.

I will be defining the uname. I want to check if that uname exists in the `part` table, and if it does, get all the `aid`s where the `active`column is equal to`1` and check that `aid` with the `activity` table and get all the corresponding details like `aname`,`adescription` etc.

Data in the tables:

[image: this is how the tables looks like]

I am hopeless in trying to write this query out. Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correctly then you can use `INNER JOIN` with both tables:

```
SELECT 
  a.*,
  p.uname
FROM activity a
  INNER JOIN part p ON a.aid = p.aid
  AND p.uname = {uname} <-- As you are defining unames -->
  AND p.active = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

By studying your requirements I get a feel that you do not require to output any data from the part table. So, I would suggest using "sub-queries" for you as it would be faster. If you require data from the part table you may want to go for INNER JOIN.

The query should using sub-query would be: -

```
    SELECT a.* FROM activity a
    WHERE a.aid IN (
    SELECT p.aid FROM part p
    WHERE p.uname = 'donor123' -- Inplace of 'donor123' please use the uname that you are searching for.
    AND p.active = 1
    );
```

The query using INNER JOIN would be: -

```
    Select a.* FROM activity a INNER JOIN part p
    ON a.aid = p.pid
    AND p.uname = 'donor123' -- Inplace of 'donor123' please use the uname that you are searching for.
    AND p.active = 1;
```

Comment: `uname` and `active` are in `part` not `activity`.